# Citrix HDX "WARNING: please install the Citrix Workspace App first."

Tags: citrix

Error installing HDX_RealTime_Media_Engine_2.9_for_Linux_x64.zip
Message "WARNING: please install the Citrix Workspace App first."

Comment: Please start with your OS & release details; what you're trying to do, where the package is from, your command & actual error message you get, along with a link to any instructions on installation you're trying to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution: There is a bug in HDXRTME_install.sh The two instances of INSTALL_HOME=$HOME/ICAClient/linuxx86 should read: INSTALL_HOME=$HOME/ICAClient/linuxx64